# git: version in the local branch is not updating

Tags: git, merge

I have built an App with Angular CLI version 6.0.8 I manage the project using GIT. I have created a feature branch my-feature-branch. In the meantime the main branch called develop has been update by other developer so I have merged the new development into my branch with the command:

```
git merge remotes/origin/develop
```

it looks like new development has been integrated into my branch but the file package.json has not been updated:

in the repo I have:

```
{
  "name": "bluebell",
  "version": "1.3.3",
  "scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
```

but in my local branch I have:

```
{
  "name": "bluebell",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
```

version to not match, Do yo know why? now I am not sure if everything in my local branch is up to date with the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are working on my-feature-branch yet.

In order to do a merge in this case.

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout my-feature-branch
git merge remotes/origin/develop
```

In case you have local changes in my-feature-branch, you need to first stash those changes, run the above 4 commands and then re-apply your stashed changes.

Assuming you are working on my-feature-branch yet.

```
git stash
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout my-feature-branch
git merge remotes/origin/develop
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

Pull the remote develop branch in your local repo and merge the updated local develop in your feature branch.